# How can I get a bean from the servlet context instead of the root context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring-mvc application which has autowired beans by use of `<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.app" />` within the `DispatcherServlet` context configuration.

I now have an situation where I wish to access a service bean from a non bean class, specifically a `RequestContextAwareTag` implementation.

I can access beans registered in the root context as follows:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(
      pageContext.getSession().getServletContext());
MyService svc = ctx.getBean(MyService.class);
```

If the bean is registered in the dispatcher context I get a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

If it's possible I would actually prefer my `@Service` beans to be registered in the root context without the `@Controller` beans being picked up, and then have the `@Controller` beans picked up in the dispatcher context. The problem with `<context:component-scan/>` is it picks up both.

If this is not possible I need a way to access the dispatchers `ApplicationContext` to retrieve the service beans.

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried implementing ApplicationContextAware and instantiating that class in your bean configuration file?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible for a tag as they are created on each page request the tag is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve this by splitting the two `component-scan` configurations by use of `exclude-filter` and `include-filter`.

root-context:

```xml
<context:component-scan  base-package="com.example.app">
  <context:exclude-filter
    expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
    type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

servlet-context:

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan  base-package="com.example.app">
  <context:include-filter
    expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
    type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: root-context means points out the bean declared one in web-xml with the tag, "context-param"?